# Code not executing on another tab in tabcontrol

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview, tabcontrol, tabpage

Hi i am a little bit confused my code not getting triggered on another tab. 
I have a tabcontrol and have a 3 Tabs on it and have a datagridview for each tab.
Datagridview1,2 and 3 for each tab.

In datagridview1 i have this code. 
This code will execute on datagridview1.cellclick.

```
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    For i = 0 To 50

        For j = 0 To 50

            If DataGridView3.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value = DataGridView2.Rows(j).Cells(0).Value Then
                DataGridView3.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.DarkSlateGray
            End If
        Next

    Next
```

If my datagridview3 is on Tabpage3 this code is not working but if i place my datagridview3 on tabpage1 the code is working properly my selected row will be color gray. Am i doing it wrong ??

Comment: I am trying to imagine what this code might do vs what you want it to do. You are going through all the rows 2500x and per iteration of i checking 50 rows for a matching condition? Maybe let us know what you're trying to accomplish. I ask because the RowPrePaint event maybe a better place for this.

Comment: Hi, Sir Tripodi i am making student evaluation system. My prof ask me that if the subject is already taken by the student it will be grayed out. on the subject list. I have image here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56052798/how-to-compare-two-datagridview-row-cell-value

Comment: I understand, are you using a datatable or bindingsource to datatable as the datasource for the DataGridViews in question?

Comment: I have updated the answer with a different solution

Comment: It is not clear “when” you are calling this code. I am guessing from your comment _”… if i place my datagridview3 on tabpage1 the code is working properly…”_  … Is it possible the “tab” page the `datagridview3` is on is NOT selected/active/displayed? Any UI commands issued to a NON displayed tab page will be ignored. I suggest you make the “tab page you want to update” selected/active/displayed BEFORE you call the code. There are numerous ways to do this. An example would be…  `tabControl1.SelectTab("tabPage2");` using the tab page name OR `tabControl1.SelectTab(1);` using the tab page index.

Answer (score 1):

Try the RowPrePaint Event.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_RowPrePaint(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.RowPrePaint
    If e.RowIndex <= 50 Then
        Dim DgvRow As DataGridViewRow = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)
        For i As Integer = 0 To 50
            If DgvRow.Cells(1).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value Then
                DgvRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.DarkSlateGray
            Else
                DgvRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Empty
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

How I would handle this situation on rows less than say 2000 is create a bindingsource to the datasource for datagridview2 and use the Find method.

IE:

```
    'Declare a new bindingsource at Class scope
    'Set its datasource to datatable used for DGV2
    Dt2BindSource.DataSource = DtSet.Tables(1)

    'Set bindingsource for DGV2 to bindingsource
    DataGridView2.DataSource = Dt2BindSource

Private Sub DataGridView1_RowPrePaint(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.RowPrePaint
    Dim DgvRow As DataGridViewRow = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)
    Dim idx As Integer = Dt2BindSource.Find("Code", DgvRow.Cells("SubjectCode").Value.ToString)
    If idx >= 0 Then
        'Code exists
        DgvRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.DarkSlateGray
    Else
        'Code no exist
        DgvRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Empty
    End If
End Sub
```